# Пересылка текста из одной формы в таблицу другой

Tags: qt, qt5, сигналы-слоты

Только начал рассматривать qt, нам дали архив с проектом, моя задача была в том, чтобы сделать добавление подразделов по кнопке в отдельной форме, доп.форму сделал, кнопку тоже, но не пойму как передавать значение из поля addEdit в столбец главной формы подраздел.
[image: Справа кнопка добавить подраздел]

По нажатию на кнопку добавить подраздел открывается форма Dobavlenie

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   dob = new Dobavlenie(this);
   dob->show();
}
```

В этой форме по нажатию на кнопку OK текст введенный в поле должен записаться в столбец подразделение из главной формы.

```
void Dobavlenie::on_buttonBox_rejected()
{
    close();
}

void Dobavlenie::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    ui->addEdit->text();
    close();
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В главной форме есть метод создания таблицы, соответственно, думаю работать нужно с ним:

```
void MainWindow::addToTable(CWorker *wr)
{
    ui->TableWidget->setRowCount(ui->TableWidget->rowCount() + 1);

    QTableWidgetItem *newItem;
    newItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
    newItem->setText(wr->GetLastName());
    ui->TableWidget->setItem(ui->TableWidget->rowCount() - 1, 0, newItem);

    newItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
    newItem->setText(wr->GetFirstName());
    ui->TableWidget->setItem(ui->TableWidget->rowCount() - 1, 1, newItem);

    newItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
    newItem->setText(wr->GetMiddleName());
    ui->TableWidget->setItem(ui->TableWidget->rowCount() - 1, 2, newItem);

    newItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
    newItem->setText(QString::number(wr->GetAccountNumber()));
    ui->TableWidget->setItem(ui->TableWidget->rowCount() - 1, 3, newItem);

    newItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
    newItem->setText(wr->GetSubDivision());
    ui->TableWidget->setItem(ui->TableWidget->rowCount() - 1, 4, newItem);

    newItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
    newItem->setText(wr->GetPosition());
    ui->TableWidget->setItem(ui->TableWidget->rowCount() - 1, 5, newItem);

    newItem = new QTableWidgetItem();
    newItem->setText(wr->GetWorkExperience());
    ui->TableWidget->setItem(ui->TableWidget->rowCount() - 1, 6, newItem);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте в `Dobavlenie` сигнал:

```
class Dobavlenie : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT
signals:
    void sectionText(QString text);
    ...
```

И тогда в методе обработки клика эмитируйте его:

```
void Dobavlenie::on_buttonBox_accepted()
{
    emit sectionText(ui->addText->text());
    close();
}
```

Теперь вы можете отлавливать этот сигнал:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
   dob = new Dobavlenie(this); // Где-то надо указатель удалить. Гемор? Гемор. Идем дальше
   connect(dob, &Dobavlenie::sectionText, [&](QString text) {
       // Добавить text в таблицу
   });
   dob->show();
}
```

НО! Лучше наследуйте `Dobavlenie` от `QDialog` и тогда ваш код существенно упростится и сократится:

```
// Создайте его через редактор с двумя кнопками
class Dobavlenie: public QDialog {
...
public:
    QString text() const {
        return ui->addText->text();
    }

}
```

И тогда:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    Dobavlenie dialog;
    if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
        QString sectionText = dialog.text();
        //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Можете подсказать, как добавить этот текст в таблицу?

Comment: @whoIam у вас же есть пример работы с таблицей, прямо в вопросе 
`auto* newItem =  new QTableWidgetItem();
newItem->setText(text);` и далее вставляете newItem в нужную ячейку

Comment: Я может неправильно понял, но я сделал так:
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    sub = new SubDivision(this);
    {auto* newItem =  new QTableWidgetItem(); newItem->setText(text);
    ui->TableWidget->setItem(ui->TableWidget->rowCount() - 1, 1, newItem);});

    sub->show();
}
И ничего не происходит при записи текста в доп.форме и нажатии на кнопку.